# Nautilus won't let me see or access files

Tags: nautilus

The last time I accessed this folder, it worked OK as it always has until this afternoon.

Today, if I open the folder, there are no files or folders listed inside it.

Nevertheless, [Files (Nautilus) says there are 641 items, and if I expand the folder, Files (Nautilus) says that it is empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsBVW.jpg).

If I right-click the folder and select Properties, [there are 3,978 items inside it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsBVW.jpg).

I know that the files were there yesterday, and I haven't deleted anything from there, so I'm confident the files and folders are there.

Does anyone know any clever ways to see and access them?

```
el_gallo_azul@W2600CR-850Pro:~$ mount | grep ^/
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/sdb1 on /mnt/InternalHDD type ext4 (rw)
/dev/sdc1 on /media/el_gallo_azul/G1 type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks2)
el_gallo_azul@W2600CR-850Pro:~$
```

sdc is the disk in question.

Comment: You most likely just need to run a file system check on that partition. It's a rather common problem with USB HDDs. If not sure about the filesystem, add the output of `mount | grep ^/` to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason these files disappeared is a mystery.

I installed nautilus-open-terminal as I mentioned above, but didn't do anything with it.

I thought that I'd check some of the other folders at the same level, to see if their contents were OK. They were. While I was there, I also opened this "Movies" folder again. Everything appeared as normal.

I have no idea why it suddenly started working correctly again. I did nothing in the meantime, including not rebooting the computer.

For the moment, this is no longer a problem. I hope it stays that way.

Answer (score 0):

Type the below command in the Terminal

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-open-terminal
```

Once you are done with the above please enter the password and open the file.

Comment: I installed nautilus-open-terminal. I then navigated to the folder/file in Nautilus. There was no change. At no point was I prompted to enter a password. What do you mean by "open the file"?

Comment: I just found http://tuxpepino.wordpress.com/2007/05/31/%C2%BFconocias-gnome-open-terminal/, where I saw that it was necessary to then `killall nautilus` and now I see a new item "Open in Terminal" in the contextual menu. Yes, all of the files that weren't listed in my first post were listed now. Now what?